# Force code execution till the end of method

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, delay, delayed-execution

I'm working on client-server multithreading application:

Progress of communication is:

1. Server listens on socket
2. Client connects and send request or requests to server
3. Each request is ended by 0x04
4. Server must proceess each request with operation which is slower than incoming requests

I have a problem in "ProcessClient" method when two requests occur in short time and first request cannot be processed till the end of method beacuse second request is coming to process. Problem occurs after foreach loop:

```
            foreach (var t in invoices)
            {
                SaveToDataBase(t);
            }
```

Method does not executes till the end and it does not sends response to client with following code snippet:

```
            var ResponseFile = ResponseClientFolder + "\\" + ResponseClientFileName + x + ".txt";
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(ResponseFile);
            sw.WriteLine(_odgovor);
            sw.Close();
            _odgovor = string.Empty;
            SendToClient(ResponseFile);
```

beacuse second request occurs at "ProcessClient" method.

Is there any way to solve this problem. I was looking for many solution without success.

Whole code is below:

```
    private void RunListener()
    {
        try
        {
            _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ServerAddres), ServerPort);
            _listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient();
                Invoke(new Action(() => { }));
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ProcessClient, client);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, @"Run listener");
        }
    }


    private void ProcessClient(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            TcpClient client = state as TcpClient;
            StringBuilder completeMessage = new StringBuilder();

            if (client == null) return;

            networkStream = client.GetStream();
            int bytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                completeMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead));
            } while (bytesRead > 0 && bytes[bytesRead - 1] != 0x04);

            completeMessage = completeMessage.Replace(@"”", "");

            string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            var x = datetime.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace(":", string.Empty).Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            var inputfilename = "Racun" + x + ".txt";

            StreamWriter sws = File.CreateText(inputfilename);
            sws.WriteLine(completeMessage);
            sws.Close(); 
            string data = completeMessage.ToString();
            char[] delimiters = { '\r', '\n' };
            string[] invoices = data.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach (var t in invoices)
            {
                SaveToDataBase(t);
            }

            var ResponseFile = ResponseClientFolder + "\\" + ResponseClientFileName + x + ".txt";
            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(ResponseFile);
            sw.WriteLine(_odgovor);
            sw.Close();
            _odgovor = string.Empty;
            SendToClient(ResponseFile);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, @"Proces client");
        }
    }

    private void SendToClient(string ResponseFile)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] byteData = File.ReadAllBytes(ResponseFile);
            List<byte> byteDat = new List<byte>();
            byteDat.AddRange(byteData);
            byteDat.Add(0x04);

            byteData = byteDat.ToArray();
            networkStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, @"Send to client");
        }
    }
```